# Multilingual Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC application does not showing language code in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET CORE application with multi lingual content. The culture is getting change successfully and it can be viewed in application cookies as well.

[image]

But the URL not changing by language switch.
What I have tried in startup is as follow:

**Startup ConfigureServices:**

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
        options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            factory.Create(typeof(ShareResource));
    });
```

**Startup Configure:**

```
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>()
{
    new CultureInfo("en"),
    new CultureInfo("de"),
    new CultureInfo("fr"),
    new CultureInfo("pt"),
    new CultureInfo("tr")
};

var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
    RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
    {
        new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
    }
};
app.UseRequestLocalization(options);

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "defaultWithLang",
        pattern: "{lang}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

And in **HomeController**:

```
public IActionResult ChangeLang(string lang)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(lang)),
        new CookieOptions(){
            Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1)
        });

    return Redirect(Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
}
```

The URL I expected to show is like "http://domain/en/controller/action" but it is not changing by switching the language and is always like "http://domain/controller/action" without language code.

Is there anything else I have to add to my code in startup or somewhere else?
Appreciated for any help.

Comment: what happens hen you manually set  url?

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu, Nothing! actually there is no different between two URLs (with and without language code)!

Answer (score 0):

what happens hen you manually set url?

right now, you are using default fallback route.

check this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "LocalizedDefault",
        template: "{lang:lang}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{*catchall}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage", lang = "en" });
```

you can also add `lang` constraint

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("lang", typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint));
});
```

then add following lines just above route configuration

```
var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```